# JavaScript: HTML entity converter (Entity to UNICODE & CSS escaped)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, unicode

I would like input an HTML entity into the field, and when I click on submit, to have it's respective UNICODE and CSS "content" code, but I am missing some things:

http://jsfiddle.net/nadqnhbc/3/

**HTML**

```
<h1>Convert HTML entities into UNICODE & CSS</h1>

<p>Example: Enter &amp;#128038; into the field.</p>
<input type="text" name="ampWhat">
<br>
<input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">


<div id="result">
    <span id="result-unicode"></span>
    <span id="result-css"></span>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {

    document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", function () {
        var entity = document.getElementById("ampWhat").value;
        alert(entity); //Code to convert into UNICODE: U+1F426 OR CSS: "/01F426"
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

To safely and accurately decode HTML entities into the original Unicode symbols, just like a browser would, use [the `he.decode(string)` functionality](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/he#hedecodehtml-options) that comes with [the *he* library](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/he):

```
var input = 'Enter &#128038; into the field.';
var decoded = he.decode(input);
console.log(decoded);
// → 'Enter  into the field.'
```

---

To convert the non-ASCII characters into a CSS escape sequence later, use [`cssesc`](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/cssesc):

```
var escaped = cssesc(decoded);
console.log(escaped);
// → 'Enter \1F426  into the field.'
```

---

Here’s a jsFiddle showing this in action: https://jsfiddle.net/mathias/fbp7bftk/

Comment: I got lost trying to download it. Can it be added to jsFiddle?

Comment: @Omar jsFiddle link added.